# `waitpid()' always returns -1

Tags: c, linux, unix, waitpid

I'm executing the code below and the call to `waitpid()` always returns `-1`, thus the code bellow ends with an infinite loop. The call works if I replace `WNOHANG` with `0`.

```
void execute(cmdLine* pCmdLine) {
    int status = 0;
    pid_t pid = fork();
    if(pid == 0) {
         if(execvp(pCmdLine->arguments[0], pCmdLine->arguments) == -1) {
             if(strcmp(pCmdLine->arguments[0], "cd") != 0) {
               perror("execute failed\n");
             }
        _exit(1);
        }
    } else {
        if(pCmdLine->blocking == 1) {
            waitpid(pid, &status, 0);
        }
            while(waitpid(pid, &status, WNOHANG) == -1) {
             printf("still -1\n");
            }
         }     
    }
}
```

Comment: You really don't have enough diagnostics in the code — test the return value of the first `waitpid()` and print it.  Check the `errno` for the `while` loop; print it and the error message.  Don't use `WNOHANG` when you want to wait for the child to die.

Answer (score 2):

Well, you have misunderstood the workings of the `wait` system call.

As with `malloc/free`, you can only successfully `waitpid()` only once per `fork()`ed process... so the `while` loop is never necessary if you are going to wait for the exit code of the child, you have to call it only once.  Wait will *only* return `-1` in your case because of two reasons:

- `fork()` didn't succeed, so you are waiting for an invalid `pid`.  Indeed, you should be calling `wait()` for `pid == -1`, which is invalid.  In case you `wait()` and there's no process to be waited for (in case the `pid` variable has a positive number, but of an already `wait()`ed subprocess, you also get `-1`), you get an error from any of the `wait()` family of system calls.  The mission of *zombie* processes in UN*X systems is just this, to ensure that a `wait()` for an already finished child is still valid and the calling process gets the exit code signalled by the child on `exit()`.
- You expressely say you are not going to wait for the process to finish.  It should be clear that if  you are not going to wait for the process to terminate, this is what you are doing with the `WNOHANG` parameter, then the child process can be still running (which is your case) and had not yet done an `exit()` syscall.  You only want the exit code in case the child process has already finished.  If this is the case, then you had better to write:

  ```
  while(waitpid(pid, &status, WNOHANG) == -1 && errno == EAGAIN)
      do_whatever_you_want_because_you_decided_not_to_wait();
  ```

  The `wait` system call has no way to tell you that the `&status` variable has not been filled with the exit code of the child process than signalling an error, and in that case, it always sets `errno` to `EAGAIN`.

  but, from my point of view, if you have nothing to do in the meanwhile, then you had better not to use `WNOHANG`.  That will save cpu cycles and a lot of heat energy thrown to the environment.

Answer (score 1):

Here

```
 while(waitpid(pid,&status,WNOHANG)==-1) { }
```

when if there is no more child process exists then `waitpid` returns `-1` and it makes `while(true)` always and that cause infinite loop.

From the manual page of `waitpid()`.

> `waitpid():` on success, returns the **process ID of the child whose
>   state has changed**; if `WNOHANG` was specified  and  one  or more
>   child(ren) specified by `pid` exist, but have not yet changed state,
>   then `0` is returned.  On error, `-1` is returned.

That means, when there are no more child to wait for, it returns `-1`. So either make it like

```
if() { /* child process. can be multiple */
} 
else { /* parent process */
    while(waitpid(pid,&status,WNOHANG) != -1) { /* when there is no more child process exists then it terminate */ 
    }
}
```

or

```
if() { /* child process. can be multiple */
} 
else { /* parent process */
  while(waitpid(pid,&status,WNOHANG) == -1);  /* dummy while ..when there is no more child process exists then it terminate */ 
}
```